# Implementing Feedback in Agile development

Tags: agile, scrum, project-planning

I just need to know about planning product development in a particular scenario.

Suppose, If I planned my sprint and executed it and then I submitted the product url for feedback and received the response from my product owner. In that case, in which sprint(Current sprint or next sprint) should  I Implement the feedback responses. What is a normal procedure for this in agile development.

Can some one clarify. 
Thanks.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you "executed" the sprint, this means that you completed the code for the feature(s) you committed to *and* that the feature(s) passed the acceptance tests your Product Owner helped write. Absent passing these tests, the feature isn't done--at least not according to Scrum (which I presume you are using if you mention a sprint and Product Owner).

If a feature doesn't pass, it isn't done. If it passes, then it is. Now at the demo at the end of the sprint, maybe other stakeholders feel the feature should do something else in addition or whatever. In that case, the new feature is added to the Product Backlog as a user story and sized and prioritized like any other.

What you describe might occur during a sprint where you just show the Product Owner something to satisfy his or her curiosity, but the only feedback that matters is passing acceptance tests that indicate the feature is production-ready.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are right, am speaking about a sprint which is submitted for acceptance, Hence not completed. From your answer, First of all I understand the feedback must be added to product backlog. Also I observe your comment further as 'to make that production ready we must move that to current sprint for execution'. Please kindly confirm.

Comment: Sort of. In true Scrum, the "feedback" is the passing or failing of a test. It isn't just a comment that says, "Yup, good job." If you failed the tests, the feature isn't done. You have until the end of the sprint to get it done (i.e. pass the tests), or it just won't count toward your velocity. If it doesn't get done, then the feature is reprioritized and resized if necessary at the next Sprint Planning. When it gets done is based on the priority. Don't assume it's the next sprint.

Comment: I agree. In the mean time I surfed about it and found different opinions. Among that I feel the one is better for me, which is very close to/exactly your comment. It says if I completed all tasks in sprint and received a response and if the sprint has to be launched to public, then the feedback must be moved to current sprint. If we are not releasing and if product owner agrees then we can move to next sprint. It explains that decision is based on situations and opinions. I feel that's very rite. Thanks for your inputs vidya.